# Add to cart the same product with different configurations

Tags: product, checkout, cart, ce-1.6.2.0, programmatically

I'm working on a Magento product configurator.
In one page, you are able to configurate multiple file, then add to cart.

Let's say, we want to add to cart the same product twice but with 2 different config.

When I do that, I have 1 only item on the cart, but with a quantity of 2. The config of the second item is totally lost.

Here is my code :

```
    $product_id = $results["product_id"];
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

    $cart = Mage::getModel("checkout/cart");
    $cart->init();

    foreach($results["params"] as $params)
        $cart->addproduct($product, $params);

    $cart->save();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should be handled by magento by default.
Try to add to cart a configurable product with 2 different configurations and you should see 2 lines in the cart.
I assume this happens to you because you don't use configurable products or custom options.
If you have some kind of custom configuration you need to tell magento to take it into consideration when matching new products added to cart to the ones that already exist.

You need to modify the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::representProduct` and make it return `false` in case your custom configurations are different from the ones already in the cart.

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck into this too.

Simply said you have to add in front of the second call of

```
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
```

a product load like in:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::_getProduct();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
  ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
  ->load($productInfo);
```

Important:

```
$cart->save()
```

has to be called only once (after foreach).

---

**Why it happens**

Used only once the function:

```
Mage_Checkout_CartController::_initProduct
```

When using

```
$cart::addProduct()
```

it reaches:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::addProductAdvanced()
```

doing:

```
$cartCandidates = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
   ->prepareForCartAdvanced($request, $product, $processMode);
```

and further ends in:

```
Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type::_prepareProduct()
```

At the end of the function there are calls to:

```
$item->addCustomOption()
```

The items are the 'candidates' (products) from array $result returned by this function.
These new "custom options" are compared in:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::representProduct
```

following the trace:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::addProductAdvanced
...
$item = $this->_addCatalogProduct($candidate, $candidate->getCartQty());

Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::_addCatalogProduct
...
$item = $this->getItemByProduct($product);

Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::getItemByProduct
...
foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
  if ($item->representProduct($product)) {
    return $item;
   }
 }
```

Basically if we don't load the product again it always compare the first product's "custom options" with sales item's "custom options".
You can see sales item's custom options in table `sales_flat_quote_item_option`.
Examples:

```
bundle_option_ids   a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;}
bundle_selection_attributes     a:4:{s:5:"price";d:312;s:3:"qty";d:1;s:12:"option_...
bundle_identity     2_125_1_2_1_4_1
selection_id    4 (maybe)
```

"buyRequest" is skipped from compare in function representProduct.

"representProduct" function works quite fine if you discount the fact that they fill a product object with identifiers for sales item. This was the trick.

Comment: thank you so much. this was the same issue with downloadable products. I wanted to add each downloadable option as a separate line item, and retrieving the product again did the trick